# jQuery offset error on Chrome & IE

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error on Chrome & IE "Cannot read property 'tagName' of null" when I try to get the offset position of an img tag width position:absolute.

html:

```
<img style=​"position:​ absolute;​" src="1.jpg">
```

js:

```
$('img').offset();
```

I search for reported bugs on jquery issues. I try jQuery 1.4.4 and 1.5.2.... but the error appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the only img in your HTML page?

Comment: I answer my self. I was including jquery.dimensions which is deprecated. :P

Comment: Please post that as an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my self. I was including jquery.dimensions which is deprecated. :P